# what is the meaning of this sentence: he gazes at a poster for The Incredible Journ...... ?

Tags: meaning

[Source](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2042568/synopsis)

> he gazes at a poster for The Incredible Journey, **wondering about all
>   his sightings of an orange cat**.

what is the meaning of this sentence?

Answer (score 2):

In the movie *Inside Llewyn Davis*, the main character, has an orange cat [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFphYRyH7wc&t=0m58s).

He sees a poster for *The Incredible Journey*  (edited to the actual poster he sees in the movie)

[image]

and focusses on the caption: "nothing could stop them - only instinct to guide them..."

This occurs after Llewyn Davis has driven from New York to Chicago and back in a few days while losing and then refinding the cat. Quite the adventure, which Llewyn later learn that "Ulysses" is the name of the cat.

It is actually unclear, to me, from the movie if he is thinking about the orange cat while looking at the poster.